# AutoCAD coordinate points

Tags: autocad

Basically I want to import an excel file containing a bunch of longitudes and latitudes into autocad. I tried using multiple points tool and pasting them in the command line with pointnording,easting  but it didn't seem to work. Any ideas

Comment: If you save your file as a CSV file or tab-delimited text file, you may be able to use my [Point Manager](http://lee-mac.com/ptmanager.html) program to import the points.

Answer (score 0):

Yep :) The thing you do is to push a so calles SCR file into Autocad. Which is nothing else as all the things you would enter to the commandline manually. This will works fine if your excel output is identically formatted. Usually the peoples which "can not program" force Excel to make a table with the autocad commands which would do the job point by point. Then they make copy and paste the thing in Excel to a text editor, save this to a file with the ending .SCR and use this. By the way a very ugly solution. Excel has VBA, Autocad has VBA !
It depends on your preferences if you want that excel drives autocad or autocad drives excel. Both is possible. I tryed both ways. Both are a bit shitty ;) The best way in my opinion is to store the data in a simple csv file. Then you just call a vba or lisp or whatever routine to do the job. Libre Office is great to deal with CSV. Anyhow, just blast the datas to autocad without any proper reformatting will not work. To test your excel thing copy one line you want to use into the acad command line. if this yells then you know your mistake. [how to write script scr files](https://www.cad-notes.com/learn-how-to-write-command-scripts-for-autocad-and-automate-your-plotting/) 
So in fact a scr file is nothing else as a plain text file which has all the things you would enter manually to get the same result. enter at the command line "SCRIPT" to load this plain text file.  Stupidly there is no logic functionallity in. For a bit more intelligence look for Autocad DIESEL. No Joke :) They call it like that. And for sure autocad has a "few" build in programming features if you know about that. DIESEL LISP VBA Whatever.NET C C++ Javascript (NO JOKE !). 
ist quite easy here a VBA sample how to drive excel by autocad :)
The sample will take excel file from r:\mappe1.xls open the table "coordinates" and draw trees like the forrester from hell ;)

```
Public Sub EXCEL_Import()
    Dim blo As AcadBlockReference
    Dim EPunkt(0 To 2) As Double
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim WTAB As Excel.WorkSheet
    Dim SHEETNAME as string
    Dim BLOCKNAME as string 

    SHEETNAME="coordinates"
    BLOCKNAME="TREE"
    Set wb = Excel.Workbooks.Open("r:\mappe1.xls")
    Set WTAB = wb.Worksheets(SHEETNAME)
    while WTAB.Cells(i, 1)<>""
        EPunkt(0) = WTAB.Cells(i, 1): EPunkt(1) = WTAB.Cells(i, 2)
        EPunkt(2) = 0
        Set blo = ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.InsertBlock _
        (EPunkt, BLOCKNAME, 1#, 1#, 1#, 0)
    wend
    wb.Close    'Datei schließen nicht vergessen
End Sub
```

Just forget to mention. To connect Autocad to Excel you has to add references to excel. (Menubar Tools / References). In the dialog look for excel.  Excel is a bit special the reference is not a dll its the EXCEL.EXE ! You may browser for it there if not listed. And for sure - if ACAD is 64 bit  - your excel should be also !. Thats why i suggest to use CSV files instead. Stupidly i have no easy to understand working example at my hands. They are a bit more "advanced" meanwhile - anayhow hoe it helps and have some fun :)